# Fonts in PyQt5 not showing up correctly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a basic gui-Window using PyQt5 under Python 3.8. This is the code I'm using:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Label')
        self.setGeometry(1000,1000,1000,1000)

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setText('Welcome to the App')

        self.show()

# create pyqt5 App
App = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# create instance of Window
window = Window()

sys.exit(App.exec())
```

I get the following error msg when I try to run it (OS: Windows 10):

```
qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to enumerate family ' "Droid Sans Mono Dotted for Powerline" ' 
qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to enumerate family ' "Droid Sans Mono Slashed for Powerline" ' 
qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to enumerate family ' "Roboto Mono Medium for Powerline" ' 
qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to enumerate family ' "Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline" '
```

Also the label is not displayed fully in the window I'm creating. I already tried to set the font of the whole application to "Arial" using the Application.setFont("Arial") method, and to set the font of the label directly via:

```
self.label_1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial'))
```

Both of these did not change the appearance of the label in my window.

Comment: use pyqt5 engine to create gui to reduce humman errors

Comment: First of all, a widget should always use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and just creating child widgets is not enough. QMainWindow already has its own internal layout, and you must add the main widget as *central* widget: add `self.setCentralWidget(self.label)`. Besides that, those warnings can probably be ignored (see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85683)

Comment: @farhanjatt what would "pyqt5 engine" mean?